# Raw function pointer vs boost::bind return value

Tags: c++, function-pointers, boost-bind

What's the difference between raw function pointer vs boost::bind pointer return value?

Comment: Not sure what answer you expect. What’s the difference between an elefant and five oranges?

Comment: @KonradRudolph the elephant can be pink, whereas oranges cannot.

Comment: @KonradRudolph an elephant can contain five oranges in itself, whereas oranges cannot contain elephant inside themselfs ;)

Comment: @StephaneRolland: Cara cara navel variety of oranges has a pinkish flesh, granted they are not pink on the outside, but maybe they are not so different from elephants deep inside.

Answer (score 4):

`bind` does not return a pointer at all. It returns an object containing a function pointer and the bound arguments, with an overloaded `operator()` that can be used to call it like a function.

So the main difference is that the result of `bind` stores the values you want to bind to function arguments; a raw pointer doesn't store anything.